# TransformException duplicate entry for com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementService.class

Tags: android, build, dependencies, android-gradle-plugin

after the update of Android Support Repository (not sure that is related) I'm getting this error while run my application for debug:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
    > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: 
    duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/measurement/AppMeasurementService.class
```

I read many answers about similar exception but I could not find one the suit mine.

These are my library dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:support-v13:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:design:${supportLibVersion}"
    compile "com.android.support:customtabs:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile 'com.bignerdranch.android:expandablerecyclerview:2.1.1'

    compile 'com.mikepenz:iconics-core:2.5.11@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1.original@aar'

    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.5.8@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }

    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:${playServicesLibVersion}"

    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:${playServicesLibVersion}"
    compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:${playServicesLibVersion}"

    compile 'com.annimon:stream:1.0.8'

    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'

    compile 'com.readystatesoftware.systembartint:systembartint:1.0.3'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'

    compile files('libs/azure/notificationhubs/notification-hubs-0.4.jar')
    compile files('libs/azure/notifications/notifications-1.0.1.jar')

    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.6.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.6.0'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
    compile ('org.simpleframework:simple-xml:2.7.1') {
        exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax-api'
        exclude group: 'stax', module: 'stax'
    }

    compile 'com.facebook.conceal:conceal:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.8.1'

    compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter:1.0.1'
    compile 'me.tatarka.bindingcollectionadapter:bindingcollectionadapter-recyclerview:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:1.3.1'
    compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'

    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
}
```

And these are my app dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    compile project(':core')              

    compile "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${supportLibVersion}"

    compile 'com.github.rey5137:material:1.2.2'
    compile 'net.opacapp:multiline-collapsingtoolbar:1.0.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.0'

    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.2.0'

    apt "org.parceler:parceler:1.0.4"
    compile 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.0.4'

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

I know that I'm supposed to remove a dependency that cause the conflict but I don't know which one I've to remove.

Need help :)
Thanks in advance

**EDIT**

I've notice right now that from Android Studio, in the Project tab, inside External Libraries there is the *play_services_measurement_8_3_0* that I've not included anywhere. During build I can also see this line:

*:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMeasurement830Library*

I've recently included the firebase library inside my project so I think that the problems is here....maybe...but I'm not able to remove it. How can I fix that?

Comment: do u have any jars in your lib folder?

Comment: @Raghavendra Yes, i've Azure Notifications Hub libraries: notifications-1.0.1.jar and notification-hubs-0.4.jar, both with sources and javadoc jars too

Comment: Having same problem after adding Azure notification with firebase-messenging  for gradle

Comment: @RasikaSugathadasa I solved this problem recreating the project from the start. It seems that Android Studio was caching something also after "clear cache and restart".